# JavascriptMVC binding doesn't work

Tags: javascript, javascriptmvc

I just want to do a simple button-click. But nothing happens on click ;-(

**Controller:**

```
$.Controller.extend('Cookbook.Controllers.Extra',
{
    onDocument: true
},
{
    "{window} load": function() {
        console.info("loaded");
    },
    'click': function( el ) {
        alert("click");
    }
});
```

**Extra.html** (entry point)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" >click here</a>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='../steal/steal.js?extra,development'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Update:

This event is working. But not the click-listener ;-(

```
 "{window} resize" : function(window, ev){alert("test")}
```

Comment: JavaScriptMVC's forums are the place to get answers.  I don't check here very often.

Answer (score 0):

The `onDocument: true` means that you've declared your Controller as a Document Controller, and Document Controllers add an implicit '#CONTROLLERNAME' before every selector.

So your event handler definition is actually:

```
'#extra click': function( el ) {
    alert("click");
}
```

You probably don't have an `#extra` element on your page, so it never gets attached, and the event is never fired. I made this mistake myself when I started using JMVC.

The first line of the [Document Controller](http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#&who=jquery.controller.documentcontrollers) documentation will explain this.

I think they may be doing away with Document Controllers in a future JMVC release, and I find that I don't use them too often.

Comment: In the {window} load handler of the Cookbook Recipe Controller it creates a div with the id "recipe" if it doesn't already exist, and all events are attached to that div. As long as an element with the correct id exists on the page your event handlers will be attached.

Answer (score 0):

There are also "MainControllers" that do not add #controllername before every selector. I believe that's what you're trying to achieve. You need to add this line to static part of controller definition:

```
hasActiveElement : document.activeElement || false
```

That would make your controller look like:

```
$.Controller.extend("MainController",{
  hasActiveElement : document.activeElement || false
},{
  focus : function(el){
     if(!this.Class.hasActiveElement)
         document.activeElement = el[0] //tracks active element
  }
})
```

Comment: Dosen't work. The cookbook example also works without this line. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Give your link an id or class, for instance

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="myLink">Click</a>
```

Then in your controller, the link registration handler should look like

```
'#myLink click': function(){
    //...
 }
```

This should work. Also note that document controllers are somehow deprecated. You should create a plain normal controller and then attach it to some element.